# Can't make a new Insertion - Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I can't Insert into this table and this drives me crazy 
This is the error Msg I get

```
var_export does not handle circular references
open: /var/www/frameworks/Scout/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
     * @param  Exception  $e
     * @param  string     $query
     * @param  array      $bindings
     * @return void
     */
    protected function handleQueryException(\Exception $e, $query, $bindings)
    {
        $bindings = var_export($bindings, true);     
        $message = $e->getMessage()." (SQL: {$query}) (Bindings: {$bindings})";
```

Here is my Full Mode

```
<?php
 namespace Models;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

  class Student extends \Eloquent
 {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $table = 'students';


/**
 * The rules used to validate new Entry.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $newValidationRules = array(
    'studentCode' => 'unique:students,code|numeric|required',
    'studentName' => 'required|min:2',
    'dateOfBirth' => 'date',
    'mobile' => 'numeric'
);

/**
 * Relation with sessions (Many To Many Relation)
 * We added with Created_at to the Pivot table as it indicates the attendance time
 */
public function sessions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Models\Session', 'student_session')->withPivot('created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
}

/**
 * Get Student Subjects depending on attendance,
 */
public function subjects()
{
    $sessions = $this->sessions()->groupBy('subject_id')->get();
    $subjects = new Collection();
    foreach ($sessions as $session) {
        $subject = $session->subject;
        $subject->setRelation('student', $this);
        $subjects->add($subject);
    }
    return $subjects;
}

/**
 * Insert New Subject
 * @return Boolean
 */

public function insertNew()
{
    $this->validator = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), $this->newValidationRules);


    if ($this->validator->passes()) {
        $this->name = \Input::get('studentName');
        $this->code = \Input::get('studentCode');
        if ($this->save()) {
            return \Response::make("You have registered the subject successfully !");
        } else {
            return \Response::make('An Error happened ');
        }
    } else {
        Return $this->validator->messages()->first();
    }
}
```

}

I am just trying to insert a new row with three Columns (I call the insertNew function on instance of Student)
1- ID automatically incremented 
2- Special Code
3- Name
And I got this above  Msg

What's I have tried till now :

1. removing all relations between from this model and other models
   that has this one in the relation
2. Removed the validation step in insertNew()
3. Removed the all Input class calls and used literal data instead.

note that I use similar Inserting function on other Models and it works flawlessly

Any Comments , Replies are appreciated :D

## Solution

I solved it and the problem was that I am accessing the validator

```
$this->validator = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), $this->newValidationRules);
```

And it was because I forgot that

```
 /**
     * The validator object.
     *
     * @var Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected $validator;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a  similar problem. But to me, changing this code:

```
if ($this->validator->passes()) {
    $this->name = \Input::get('studentName');
    $this->code = \Input::get('studentCode');"
```

to this:

```
if ($this->validator->passes()) {
     $this->setAttribute ("name" , \Input::get('studentName'));
     $this->setAttribute ("code" , \Input::get('studentCode'));"
```

solved it.